# Drop down select list modification

Tags: javascript, jquery

Thanks to lvoely people on this website, I am slowly getting this script to work as I intended. One thing I couldn't figure out is

1. how to get "State" (select2) to show "Select State" instead straight to options when Country (Select 1) is selected and, simililarly, ""City" to show "Select City" instead of straight to options when "State" (Select2) is selected).
2. how to make City (select3) to show "Select City" when previously selected "State" (select2) is unselected or changed to another State. Likewise for "State" when previously selected "Country" is unselected or changed to another Country (also for City to change to "Select City" when this happens)

```js
$(function() {
  $("#select1").change(function() {
    if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
      $(this).data('options', $('#select2 option').clone());
    }
    var id = $(this).val();
    if (id == "") {
      $('#select2').val('');
      $('#select3').val('');
      return;
    }
    var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[data-value=' + id + ']');
    $('#select2').html(options).show();
  });

  $("#select2").change(function() {
    if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
      $(this).data('options', $('#select3 option').clone());
    }
    var id = $(this).val();
    if (id == "") {
      $('#select3').val('');
      return;
    }
    var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[data-value=' + id + ']');
    $('#select3').html(options).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="select1" id="select1">
  <option value="">Select Country</option>
  <option value="india">India</option>
  <option value="america">America</option>
</select>

<select name="select2" id="select2" style="inline">
  <option value="">Select State</option>
  <option data-value="india" value="orissa">Orissa</option>
  <option data-value="india" value="telangan">Telangan</option>
  <option data-value="america" value="usa">USA</option>
  <option data-value="america" value="america">California</option>
</select>

<select name="select3" id="select3" style="inline">
  <option value="">Select city</option>
  <option data-value="orissa">Nal</option>
  <option data-value="orissa">Mir</option>
  <option data-value="telangan">Hyd</option>
  <option data-value="telangan">Vija</option>
  <option data-value="usa">ttt</option>
  <option data-value="usa">ttt</option>
  <option data-value="america">KRK</option>
  <option data-value="america">MRK</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The lines

```
var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[data-value=' + id + ']');
$('#select2').html(options).show();
```

remove all options and replace them with *only* the ones that match the filter - obviously(?) the "please select" (value="") `option` does not match, so is not included.

You could adjust your filter to include it, or add the blank option to the `select` after.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#select1").change(function() {
    if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
      $(this).data('options', $('#select2 option').clone());
    }
    var id = $(this).val();
    if (id == "") {
      $('#select2').val('');
      $('#select3').val('');
      return;
    }
    var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[data-value=' + id + '],[value=""]');
    $('#select2').html(options).show();
  });

  $("#select2").change(function() {
    if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
      $(this).data('options', $('#select3 option').clone());
    }
    var id = $(this).val();
    if (id == "") {
      $('#select3').val('');
      return;
    }
    var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[data-value=' + id + '],[value=""]');
    $('#select3').html(options).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="select1" id="select1">
  <option value="">Select Country</option>
  <option value="india">India</option>
  <option value="america">America</option>
</select>

<select name="select2" id="select2" style="inline">
  <option value="">Select State</option>
  <option data-value="india" value="orissa">Orissa</option>
  <option data-value="india" value="telangan">Telangan</option>
  <option data-value="america" value="usa">USA</option>
  <option data-value="america" value="america">California</option>
</select>

<select name="select3" id="select3" style="inline">
  <option value="">Select city</option>
  <option data-value="orissa">Nal</option>
  <option data-value="orissa">Mir</option>
  <option data-value="telangan">Hyd</option>
  <option data-value="telangan">Vija</option>
  <option data-value="usa">ttt</option>
  <option data-value="usa">ttt</option>
  <option data-value="america">KRK</option>
  <option data-value="america">MRK</option>
</select>
```

---

Refactored for easier calls

```js
$(function() {

  init();
  reset("#select1", "#select2");
  reset("#select1", "#select3");
  
  $("#select1").change(function() {
  
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value == "") {
      reset("#select1", "#select2");
      reset("#select1", "#select3");
    }
    else {
      set("#select2", value);
      reset("#select2", "#select3");
    }
  });

  $("#select2").change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value == "") {
      reset("#select2", "#select3");
    }
    else {
      set("#select3", value);
    }
  });
  
  function init() {
    $("select").each(function() {
      $(this).data('options', $(this).find('option').clone());
    });
  }
  
  function reset(parent, child) {
    var opts = $(parent).data("options").filter('[value=""]');
    $(child).html(opts.clone());
  }
  
  function set(select, value) {
    var options = $(select).data('options').filter(`[data-value='${value}'],[value=""]`);
    $(select).html(options.clone()).show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="select1" id="select1">
  <option value="">Select Country</option>
  <option value="india">India</option>
  <option value="america">America</option>
</select>

<select name="select2" id="select2" style="inline">
  <option value="">Select State</option>
  <option data-value="india" value="orissa">Orissa</option>
  <option data-value="india" value="telangan">Telangan</option>
  <option data-value="america" value="usa">USA</option>
  <option data-value="america" value="america">California</option>
</select>

<select name="select3" id="select3" style="inline">
  <option value="">Select city</option>
  <option data-value="orissa">Nal</option>
  <option data-value="orissa">Mir</option>
  <option data-value="telangan">Hyd</option>
  <option data-value="telangan">Vija</option>
  <option data-value="usa">ttt</option>
  <option data-value="usa">ttt</option>
  <option data-value="america">KRK</option>
  <option data-value="america">MRK</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks! Two problems remained though. 1) Both the "State" and "City" are not disabled when the country is not selected. The "city" is not disabled when the state is not selected. 2) After complete all three selection, if I choose another country say from India to USA, neither the state and the city gets resetted to "select state" and "select city"

Comment: There's no mention of making elements enabled/disabled in your question.  If you want to reset city when country changes, then add the code to reset.  I suggest (but didn't at the time have the time) that you separate your initialisation (copying into data-) from the updates - you can also separate the reset from the set and call reset as required.

Comment: Added an edit that refactors your calls to reduce DRY.  You can add enable/disable if you need to, but by copying the "select country" into the state/city, it's becomes instructional that the user needs to select country before they can select state.